# Visual Studio Code 1.57 (2021 download and installation) error : cannot activate the "GitHub" extension

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, github-api

I'm getting error message:

```
 Cannot activate Github extension 
 because it depends on an unknown vscode.git extension
```

Is it somehow conflicting with other extensions I have installed?
Appreciate any guidance.

Illustration:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You either have a conflict with the installed extensions or a required extension is disabled.

Comment: Please note that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are very different applications. I've updated the question and tags to be correct in referring to Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "GitHub" extension in question should be the [`microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github), which, in [its issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20activate%20unknown), does not mention anything about `active` and `unknown` at all.

I just tested on my VSCode 1.57, and clicking on that link does work.

Try and disable other plugins installed to see if one might cause the issue.

The [OP JimBoyLim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15977777/jimboylim) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67945654/visual-studio-1-57-2021-download-and-installation-error-cannot-activate-the/67945886#comment120164993_67945886):

> I finally just reinstalled VSCode, and now its working!

Comment: Thanks for quick replies...I tried disabling other plugins and when i click "clone repository" again, i get the error : "it looks like Git is not installed on your system".  Do i need to install it? i thought its built-in to the 2021 version?

Comment: @JimBoyLim I would recommend installing it, and making sure it is in your PATH, before launching VSCode again, and see if that makes a difference in your case.

Comment: you mean uninstalling and then re-installing again? How do i ensure it is in my PATH? (sorry for this newbie question)

Comment: @JimBoyLim I meant installing the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases): then typing in a new CMD where git: that will insure the setup process did add Git to your `%PATH%`. Then launching VSCode again.

Comment: i followed your suggestion but it still has no effect. i still get the same message above + "cannot activate the "GitHub" extension because it depends on an unknown vscode.git extension. ....

Comment: @JimBoyLim What does `git version`, `where git` and `where ssh` return?

Comment: i finally just reinstalled VS and now its working! thanks guys!

Comment: @JimBoyLim Great, well done. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.